# Magento 2 : Set free shipping method programatically from an observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipping-methods

I need to add free shipping method fro particular quote in an observer.
I am calling an event `sales_quote_collect_totals_before`.

And my observer code is -

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    { 
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $address->setFreeShipping(true);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your observer :

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setFreeShipping(true);
$quote->save();
```

It may be helpful for you.

Comment: No, It is not working. Right now, the shipping methods which are available are listed on checkout page. I don't want to give user an option and set shipping method free on particular condition.
Please do suggest as I am new in magento.

Answer (score 0):

use below

```
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $shippingMethod= 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                    ->collectShippingRates()
                    ->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod)
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates();
    $quote->collectTotals();
    $quote->save();
```